# Расположение элементов в шапке

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, flexbox

Элементы в шапке должны располагаться как на https://krasnodar.rbt.ru/utm_referrer=https%3a%2f%2fwww.yandex.ru%2f.

У меня же элементы располагаются как на [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться нужного отображения? Привожу код

```css
#pageHeader {
    grid-area: header;
    width: 100%;
    /*
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    */
}

#pageHeader .mainpart {
        padding-left: 10px;
        /*padding-right: auto;*/
        /*width: 1200px;*/
        align-self: center;
        /*border-bottom: 2.5px dotted black;*/
        font: 18px, PT Sans,sans-serif;
        /*white-space: pre;*/
}

#pageHeader .headerinsides {
        padding-left: 74px;
        /*padding-right: 74px;*/
        width: 1200px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
}

.icon {
        align-self: center;
        /*padding-left: 74px;*/
        /*padding-right: 74px;*/
}

.flexcitylink{
        /*margin-left: 74px;*/
        display: flex;
        /*border-bottom: 5px dotted black;*/
        font: 18px, PT Sans,sans-serif;
}

.intermediatespace {
        flex: 3;
}

.telephonenumber {
        flex: 3;
}

.addressandworkschedule {
        flex: 1;
}

.payment {
        flex: 1;
}

.delivery {
        flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
<div class="headerinsides">
        <a href="#" class="flexcitylink">
                <div class="icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="Sg" width="16" height="16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.057 8a2.012 2.012 0 01-2.019-2c0-1.103.906-2 2.02-2 1.113 0 2.018.897 2.018 2s-.905 2-2.019 2zm0-5C6.387 3 5.03 4.346 5.03 6s1.358 3 3.028 3 3.029-1.346 3.029-3-1.359-3-3.029-3zm0 11.777C6.852 13.5 3.01 9.177 3.01 6c0-2.757 2.264-5 5.047-5 2.784 0 5.047 2.243 5.047 5 0 3.174-3.841 7.5-5.047 8.777zM8.057 0C4.717 0 2 2.691 2 6c0 4.159 5.468 9.623 5.7 9.854a.509.509 0 00.714 0c.233-.23 5.7-5.695 5.7-9.854 0-3.309-2.716-6-6.057-6z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
                        <!--<i class="i-icon i-icon-fl-location">
                        :before
                        </i>-->
                </div>
                <div class="mainpart">
                 Краснодар
                </div>
        </a>
                <div class="intermediatespace">
                </div>
                <div class="telephonenumber">
                8 (800)6003900 (круглосуточно)
                </div>
                <div class="addressandworkschedule">
                    Адрес и график работы
                </div>
                <div class="payment">
                    Оплата
                </div>
                <div class="delivery">
                    Доставка
                </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Привожу код для удобства https://jsfiddle.net/vladdvin/Lfh61ug5/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам нужное направление - используйте `<table>`.

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
    <table style="width:100%;" class="headerinsides">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="flexcitylink">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="Sg" width="16" height="16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.057 8a2.012 2.012 0 01-2.019-2c0-1.103.906-2 2.02-2 1.113 0 2.018.897 2.018 2s-.905 2-2.019 2zm0-5C6.387 3 5.03 4.346 5.03 6s1.358 3 3.028 3 3.029-1.346 3.029-3-1.359-3-3.029-3zm0 11.777C6.852 13.5 3.01 9.177 3.01 6c0-2.757 2.264-5 5.047-5 2.784 0 5.047 2.243 5.047 5 0 3.174-3.841 7.5-5.047 8.777zM8.057 0C4.717 0 2 2.691 2 6c0 4.159 5.468 9.623 5.7 9.854a.509.509 0 00.714 0c.233-.23 5.7-5.695 5.7-9.854 0-3.309-2.716-6-6.057-6z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
                        <!--<i class="i-icon i-icon-fl-location">
                        :before
                        </i>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="mainpart">
                        Краснодар
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="intermediatespace">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="telephonenumber">
                    8 (800)6003900 (круглосуточно)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="addressandworkschedule">
                    Адрес и график работы
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="payment">
                    Оплата
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="delivery">
                    Доставка
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </header>
```

Comment: а с помощью flex-а можете сделать?

Comment: @newbieseeker поэксперементируйте, я же вам не могу всю работу за вас сделать. Если не хотите разбиратся, наймите фрилансера, он вам все сделает.

Comment: Удалите этот вопрос.